# taking a value from double list and making it a menu

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list of data that reads

```
[['name','emailtype','phonetype'],['john','yahoomail', 'mobile'],['mark','yahoo','landline']]
```

I can manually pick out the values i.e `print dL[0][0]` prints `name` and `dL[1][0]` `emailtype`.

Is it possible to isolate all the names from the list. i.e `john` and `mark`. With a program / module and then print them
and produce them into something like this:

```
1) John
2) Mark
```

so that I can ask for a `raw_input` and then if I press 1 as selection it produces `john` as the answer.

so that it reads similar to the nicely written data that I can manually type as above.

Comment: It's possible if you know how to recognise a name.

Comment: in that case do i have to write a function defining what the name is or would it be easier to just create a list of the names individually rather then creating them as a double list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to slice the list (to ignore the first row), then use a list comprehension to pick out just the first element of each nested list:

```
[row[0] for row in nested_list[1:]]
```

Comment: Awesome thanks Martijn thats exactly what i was chasing to split the names out your a lifesaver.Would you know how to then place a number in front of each name?

Comment: @user2343337 `['{}) {}'.format(index+1, row[0]) for index, row in enumerate(nested_list[1:])]`

Comment: @user2343337: Use `enumerate()` to generate indices to go with each list; Thijs's example gives you a list of names with numbers formatted the same way as your output, but you can loop over the list I gave in my answer too.